# Page not being converted into xml format

Tags: php, xml, curl

I am grabbing a page and then converting it into an xml format, the function im using is below

```
public function getXML($url){
   $ch = curl_init();
   //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
   //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
   $response = curl_exec($ch);      
   $xml = simplexml_load_string($response);
   return $xml;
}

print_r($curl->getXML("http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/offer-listing/0292783760/ref=tmm_pap_new_olp_sr?ie=UTF8&condition=used"));
```

After trying different urls nothing is returned, the page loads fine so the problem is with the line `$xml = simplexml_load_string($response);`

What could be wrong with this code?

Comment: when you enable `error_reporting(E_ALL)` and `ini_set('display_errors', true)`, what do you see?

Comment: @Kato a lot of errors, it would be too much to copy and paste, but I get something like `Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 1408: parser error : Opening and ending tag mismatch: link line...`

Comment: can i ask why you are converting to XML ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not understanding exactly what you're up to, it looks like you're trying to scrape the Amazon web page? If I pull up that URL in my browser, it's not listed as XHTML in the headers or document itself--I suspect it's not. I don't think simplexml can handle that.

(Does CURL do the conversion to XML for you? I don't think so but I'm not a master of all things CURL. If so, it might be an incompatability between CURL's output and what simplxml--which is fairly limited--will take in).

You might try working with DOMDocument instead, although my PHP could be a bit out of date--there may be better utilities these days.

[A quick googling brought up this tutorial](http://drewish.com/content/2007/08/using_simplexml_with_html)

```
<?php
  $doc = new DOMDocument();
  $doc->strictErrorChecking = FALSE;
  $doc->loadHTML($html);
  $xml = simplexml_import_dom($doc);
?>
```

I don't think this is a complete answer, but it was a bit much for a comment; so take it with a grain of salt and a healthy serving of doubt. I hope it inspires some ideas.